# How do I run loops while keeping events running?

Tags: java, multithreading, loops, events, boolean

I have a question about using events to run loops since doing so seems to lock down the thread. For example I have an nativeMousePressed and nativeMouseReleased event and I am trying to execute some code continuously while the mouse is pressed and then stop when its released. I tried to do this by creating a static boolean variable in another manager class and then setting it to true when the mouse is being pressed and false when the mouse is released. Then I decided to make a while loop that gets called from inside that nativeMousePressed event that uses the boolean value I talked about earlier. The issue is that no events can be called while that while loop is running which means the boolean value when never become false creating an infinite loop. How can I run the while loop while keeping the events running as well?

I assume this has to do with the thread being locked down but I have not worked with stuff like this much and would like some help figuring out how to run both these things in parallel.

```
public class NativeMouseEvent implements NativeMouseListener {
Program program = new Program();

@Override
public void nativeMouseClicked(org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void nativeMousePressed(org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent e) {

    if(e.getButton() == 1 && Controller.threeClicked) {
        Controller.fixAim = true;
        program.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void nativeMouseReleased(org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent e) {
    program.interrupt();
    Controller.fixAim = false;
}
}
```

Here is what my second thread is running...

```
public class Program extends Thread {

public void run() {
    while(Controller.fixAim) {
        System.out.println("test");
    }
}
```

Here my second attempt which also gives me an error saying that this.program is null.

```
public class NativeMouseEvent implements NativeMouseListener {
Program program;

@Override
public void nativeMouseClicked(org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent e) {
}

@Override
public void nativeMousePressed(org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent e) {

    if(e.getButton() == 1 && Controller.threeClicked) {
        Controller.fixAim = true;
        if(program != null) {
            program = new Program();
            program.start();
        }

    }
}

@Override
public void nativeMouseReleased(org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent e) {
    program.interrupt();
    program = null;
    Controller.fixAim = false;
}
}
```

Comment: What is the code that you want to execute continuously while the mouse is down doing?

Comment: In your thread don't run code continuously add some sleep `Thread.sleep(100);` so that other threads can do their jobs. Instead of global variable try to use `thread.interrupt()` method and handle InterruptedException inside thread to gracefully terminate.

Comment: See method 2 in this article [killing threads](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/killing-threads-in-java/)

Comment: I added some code for context (my goal is to draw circles in a canvas app). Anyways I need a loop to run continuously till the mouseReleased event is triggered but if I make the thread sleep wont that pause the loop?

Comment: Yes, you do not want to sleep in the event thread. I don't know what sort of program you're writing, so I can't tell you what to do, but you could start another thread, or probably better use a timer to execute some code periodically.

Comment: The best thing for you to do would be to provide a complete, runnable example which illustrates the issue.

Comment: That is basically all the code since I made a different question about drawing circles that build off of your mouse movements on a canvas. That being said for this question just imagine that inside that  nativeMousePressed event I call a while loop that does literally anything for example prints a statement like "test". So I basically want to a while loop to keep printing the word "test" while my mouse button is held down and as soon as I release my mouse button I want it to stop printing the world "test". (My events are provided above)

Comment: @UnSure I thought you were using separate thread for drawing stuff while button pressed. Obviously don't sleep in event thread. In nativeMousePressed create a new thread and do your circle drawing there and kill the thread in nativeMouseReleased using `thread.interrupt()`. Also make sure your circle drawing thread sleeps for some milliseconds so that other threads get to do their jobs.

Comment: nativeMouseReleased can be called when program is null, because you have that if statement around its creation. Check that program isn't null before calling interrupt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start a tread on mouse down and stop the tread on mouse up. In the thread do circle drawing.
Something like below java code. Note: it is just an example. You need to make changes to make it work in your android environment.

```java
public class Test { 
    Thread drawTask;
    
    public void mouseDown() {
        drawTask = new Thread(()-> {
            int i = 0;
            try {
                for(;;) {
                    System.out.print("\rDrawing circle " + i++);
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                }
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("finished drawing circle.");
            }
        });
        
        drawTask.start();
    }
    
    public void mouseUp() {
        if(drawTask != null) {
            drawTask.interrupt();
            drawTask = null;  //<--- make sure you do this
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("type anything and press Enter to simulate mouse down/up");
        in.next();
        
        test.mouseDown();
        
        in.next();
        test.mouseUp();
        
        in.next();
        in.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: I did some googling and I updated my initial post with what I have now. Also I will mark your answer as accepted right after this one little bug is fixed. Anyways it works perfectly the first time but if I press my mouse click down again I get an exception on the line where I start the thread again which states "Exception in thread "JNativeHook Native Dispatch" java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException" any ideas?

Comment: I assume its because I am starting it again even though its already running since in the release method I only interrupted it. Should I instead call program.stop() I ask this because its depreciated. Or I could just check if its running and if it is I could call program.resume() but once again that is also deprecated. I am not really sure the solution here I am just looking at my options.

Comment: You need to create a new thread object every time mouse button goes down. You can't reuse the same thread object. As the thread has completed it's execution when you start it again it throws Illigal state exception. Also make `drawTask = null;` in mouse up so that you won't use the same thread object again.

Comment: I updated my post again with my second attempt but I am now getting a null error. I dont have the same set up as you could you possibly tell me what I am doing wrong in my code?

Comment: in `nativeMouseReleased` use null check `if(program != null) {` for `program.interrupt();` also in `nativeMousePressed` get rid of the null check `if(program != null) {`.